# From JSONObject to ListView()

Tags: android

basically I have some data stories in an API in JSON format.

I have managed to get the data from the JSON, loop through the, put them into a TextView, add onClick() on the textView.

but I want to be able to use the optical button on the phone to scroll, so I been told I need a ListView()

So I put the text I want into an array and added the array to the listView

As the example shows below
But how do I add onClick for each Item and pass the ID (intStoryID)?????????

My Code Example

```
 BufferedReader jsonBr = null;
 ArrayList arrStoryList = null;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.stories_main);

    if(setTopStoryData()){ 
          setStoriesArray();
          buildPage();
    }else{
       // TODO add Error Handling
    } 

  }

 public boolean setTopStoryData(){
      String strURL = "http://www.example.com/api/index.php?my=params";

     JSONConn jsonConn = new JSONConn();
     JSONConn.setURL(strURL);
     if(jsonConn.setData()){
        jsonBr = jsonConn.Br();
        return true;
     }else{
          // my Error Handling
          return false;
     }
 }


      public void setStoriesArray(){
    String line;
    String strAddDate;
    String strCurrentStatus;
    String strStatusRead;
    int intStoryID;
    int intNumStories;

    arrStoryList = new ArrayList();

    JSONObject arrStories;
    JSONObject arrAllStories;
    JSONObject arrSingleStory;
    try{

        while((line = jsonBr.readLine()) != null){
            arrStories      = new JSONObject(line);
            intNumStories   = Integer.parseInt(arrStories.optString("NumStories"));
            arrAllStories   = arrStories.getJSONObject("StoryData");

            if(intNumStories > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < intNumStories; i++){
                    arrSingleStory = arrAllStories.getJSONObject("Story"+i);

                    intStoryID  = Integer.parseInt(arrSingleStory.getString("ID"));
                    strAddDate  = arrSingleStory.getString("ADDEDDATE");
                    strCurrentStatus    = arrSingleStory.getString("CURRENTSTATUS");

                    if(strCurrentStatus.equals("y")){
                        strStatusRead = "Online";
                    }else if(strCurrentStatus.equals("n")){
                        strStatusRead = "Offline";
                    }else{
                        strStatusRead = "Pending";
                    }

                    String strStoryText =  strAddDate+" - " +strCurrentStatus;
                    arrStoryList.add(strStoryText));


                } // end FOR loop
            }


        } //End while loop


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        strDEBUG += "Error (2)";
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        strDEBUG += "Error (3) "+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n";
    }
      }

  public void buildPage(){
    if(this.arrStoryList != null){
        ListView lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.arrStoryList));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `onItemClickListener()` to the list view to get click event on each item

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
               int position, long id) {
           // do whatever you want here
       }
   });
```

Comment: But I want to pass the story ID for the item they clicked on, how do I get that into the array?

Comment: you can get position of item and from arraylist by passing position you can get storyID if you have stored in the arraylist

Comment: So basically I need to store 2 arrays
One with the text I want in the ListView(), the other with the StoryID
Then match the Key from the selected ListVIew array to connect to the StoryID